# QWebView crashing when loading url

Tags: python, qt, maya, pyside2

I'm using `PySide2` inside of Maya to create a widget with a `QWebView` that loads google.com on its `showEvent`.

I'm able to run this with no problems outside of Maya as a standalone tool, but inside Maya it will immediately crash when I use its `load` method. It's weird because as Maya crashes I do see google successfully loaded in my widget.

I'm using Maya 2018 extension 4 on Centos 7. Can someone confirm that this is crashing on your machine too?

Here's the script I'm running that crashes for me everytime:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtWebKitWidgets


class BrowserTool(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BrowserTool, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(800, 800)

        self.web_view = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(parent=self)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.web_view)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.web_view.load("http://www.google.com")


tool = BrowserTool()
tool.show()
```

Here's contents Maya spits out from its crash file:

```
//====================================================
//command history (most recent last):
//====================================================
//last tool: nurbsSelect
//====================================================
//panel with focus: scriptEditorPanel1
//visible panels:
// modelPanel4 outlinerPanel1 scriptEditorPanel1 
//====================================================
  /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x1617dc) [0x7f33f10707dc]
  OBJ_bsearch_ex
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libcrypto.so.6(+0x7e125) [0x7f334111b125]
  X509_OBJECT_retrieve_match
  X509_STORE_add_cert
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xfd5dc) [0x7f33e4ddc5dc]
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0x100d9a) [0x7f33e4ddfd9a]
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0x103512) [0x7f33e4de2512]
  QSslSocket::startClientEncryption()
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xeddb0) [0x7f33e4dccdb0]
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xf56d9) [0x7f33e4dd46d9]
  QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**)
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xcea6b) [0x7f33e4dada6b]
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xd0b98) [0x7f33e4dafb98]
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5(+0xd9165) [0x7f33e4db8165]
  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
  QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libExtensionLayer.so(+0x1edc3c) [0x7f3400af0c3c]
  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x2c3bfe) [0x7f33f6489bfe]
  g_main_context_dispatch
  /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4a818) [0x7f33dc8b1818]
  g_main_context_iteration
  QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
  QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
  QThread::exec()
  /Volumes/apps/x86_64/maya/2018_EXT4/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0xaa9d3) [0x7f33f62709d3]
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7f33f12d9e25]
  clone
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's `load` that's causing the problem? It seems plausible that using `showEvent` could also be problematic. What happens if you comment out the `showEvent` line, so that `load` is called in `__init__` instead? Or perhaps try using a timer to load the url after a small delay. You could also try adding `super(BrowserTool, self).showEvent(event)` at the start of `showEvent`.

Comment: Pretty sure it was still crashing on `load` even if I had it inside of `__init__` instead, but I'll give it a try. This script is working ok on my home Windows machine in 2018, so that's not promising!

Comment: Removing `showEvent` still crashes it. I also tried creating a button and using `load` on its `clicked` event. I'll click it, google loads, then it crashes.

Comment: One last thing to do is try the original script with PyQt5. If it still crashes, you can be pretty certain the bug is in Maya; if not, it must be in PySide2. You could also try it with PySide/Qt4 to narrow things down a bit further.

Comment: I managed to get it working on my Windows machine with `PySide2`, so I have a feeling something's fishy with my Maya's environment on Linux. I remember a while ago it had issues opening up a browser from Maya, so maybe some environment variables are causing conflicts. It's hard to say.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that this event is called several times in a short period. The documentation says: _Non-spontaneous show events are sent to widgets immediately before they are shown. The spontaneous show events of windows are delivered afterwards._